# MaterialDesignThemes Wpf TimePicker as Non Typable

Tags: wpf, timepicker, materialdesignthemes

```
MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.TimePicker timePicker = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.TimePicker();
            timePicker.Name = name.Replace("/", "000").Trim();
            timePicker.Tag = name;
            timePicker.Is24Hours = true;
            timePicker.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MaterialDesignTimePicker"];
            timePicker.PreviewTextInput += NumberValidationTextBox;
            timePicker.Margin = new Thickness(10);
            timePicker.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            timePicker.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            timePicker.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

I am creating a time picker from material Design Themes. Now the time picker has option to select time from clock or can type text, I want to make the time picker non typable. Only user can select the time from the clock.

Answer (score 0):

To make the MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.TimePicker non-typable, you can disable the keyboard input for the control. You can do this by handling the PreviewKeyDown event and setting the Handled property of the event arguments to true to prevent any key presses from being processed. Here's how you can modify your code:

```html
MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.TimePicker timePicker = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.TimePicker();
timePicker.Name = name.Replace("/", "000").Trim();
timePicker.Tag = name;
timePicker.Is24Hours = true;
timePicker.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MaterialDesignTimePicker"];
timePicker.PreviewTextInput += NumberValidationTextBox;
timePicker.PreviewKeyDown += (sender, e) =>
{
    // Prevent any keyboard input
    e.Handled = true;
};
timePicker.Margin = new Thickness(10);
timePicker.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
timePicker.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
timePicker.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

By adding the PreviewKeyDown event handler and setting e.Handled = true; inside it, you're effectively preventing any keyboard input in the TimePicker, making it non-typable while still allowing the user to select the time from the clock.